# Dependency between operations in scala actors

Tags: scala, actor

I am trying to parallelise a code using scala actors. That is my first real code with actors, but I have some experience with Java Mulithreading and MPI in C. However I am completely lost.

The workflow I want to realise is a circular pipeline and can be described as the following:

- Each *worker* actor has a reference to another one, thus forming a circle
- There is a *coordinator* actor which can trigger a computation by sending a `StartWork()` message
- When a worker receives a `StartWork()` message, it process some stuff locally and sends `DoWork(...)` message to its neighbour in the circle.
- The neighbours do some other stuff and sends in turn a `DoWork(...)` message to its own neighbour.
- This continues until the initial worker receives a `DoWork()` message.
- The coordinator can send a `GetResult()` message to the initial worker and wait for a reply.

The point is that the coordinator should only receive a result when data is ready. **How can a worker wait that the job returned to it before answering the `GetResult()` message ?**

To speed up computation, any worker can receive a `StartWork()` at any time.

Here is my first try pseudo-implementation of the worker:

```
class Worker( neighbor: Worker, numWorkers: Int ) {
   var ready = Foo()
   def act() {
     case StartWork() => { 
       val someData = doStuff()
       neighbor ! DoWork( someData, numWorkers-1 ) 
       }
     case DoWork( resultData, remaining ) => if( remaining == 0 ) {
         ready = resultData
       } else {
         val someOtherData = doOtherStuff( resultData )
         neighbor ! DoWork( someOtherData, remaining-1 )
      }
    case GetResult() => reply( ready )
  }
}
```

On the coordinator side:

```
worker ! StartWork()
val result = worker !? GetResult() // should wait
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you clearly need to have some identifier of what constitutes a single piece of work, so that the `GetResult` can get the correct result. I guess the obvious solution is to have your actors keep a `Map` of the results and a `Map` of any waiting *getters*:

```
class Worker( neighbor: Worker, numWorkers: Int ) {
   var res: Map[Long, Result] = Map.empty
   var gets: Map[Long, OutputChannel[Any]] = Map.empty   
   def act() {
     ...
     case DoWork( id, resultData, remaining ) if remaining == 0 =>
       res += (id -> resultData)
       gets.get(id).foreach(_ ! res(id)) //reply to getters when result is ready
       gets -= id //clear out getter map now?
     case GetResult(id) if res.isDefinedAt(d) => //result is ready
       reply (res(id))
     case GetResult(id) => //no result ready 
       gets += (id -> sender)
   }
}
```

**Note:** the use of `if` in the matching condition can make message processing a bit clearer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try it as soon as possible. BTW the I think the if after the `=>` was correct in this case. I am not looking for a guard when matching params, but I would like to have two different behaviours according to a value. Perhaps I should use two `case` entries whith different guards.

Comment: Oh, yes. So it was - I was reading the `=>` to be somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be this:

```
class Worker( neighbor: Worker, numWorkers: Int ) {
   var ready = Foo()
   def act() {
     case StartWork() => { 
       val someData = doStuff()
       neighbor ! DoWork( someData, numWorkers-1 ) 
       }
     case DoWork( resultData, remaining ) => if( remaining == 0 ) {
         ready = resultData
         react {
           case GetResult() => reply( ready )
         }
       } else {
         val someOtherData = doOtherStuff( resultData )
         neighbor ! DoWork( someOtherData, remaining-1 )
      }
  }
}
```

After the work has finished, this worker will be stuck until it receives the `GetResult` message. On the other hand, the coordinator can immediately send the `GetResult`, as it will remain in the mailbox until the worker receives it.

Comment: Really nice. I did not realise that react blocks can be embedded. However, that's not a solution for my problem because (if I understand correctly) the worker will be stuck in the inner `react` waiting for a `GetResult()` and will not be able to be part of the pipeline.

Comment: @paradigmatic Only if the result is ready will it stop to wait for `GetResult`, but my point was really showing that you could cascade reactions.